# Correct raise translation for python 3.7 w two arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, exception

How do I convert this code from Python 2 to to Python 3:

```py
except ET.XMLSyntaxError, log:
    #This exception raised if the file has parse errors in it
    logging.error("XSD: " + log.message)        
    raise SyntaxError, log.message
```

I'm not actually sure what the `raise` line is doing. I've already replaced

```py
except ET.XMLSyntaxError, log:
```

with

```py
except ET.XMLSyntaxError as log:
```

Background: I upgraded my system to python 3.7 and our build is not working with a number of Python scripts though it might be faster to update our scripts to Python 3 than revert my ubuntu environment.

Comment: `raise SyntaxError(log.message)` https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate fix for you is this:

```
raise SyntaxError(log.message)
```

If you have a lot of Python 2.x scripts, I'd recommend using the [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) tool to have it translate from python 2.x to 3.x. The documentation even calls out the `raise` change you're asking for here:

> `raise`
>
> Converts `raise E, V` to `raise E(V)`, and `raise E, V, T` to
> `raise E(V).with_traceback(T)`. If `E` is a `tuple`, the translation will be
> incorrect because substituting tuples for exceptions has been removed
> in 3.0.

Here's a snippet with a piece of code that's in Python 2.x exception format that we'll run `2to3` on:

```
import logging

try:
    print "hello"
except Exception, log:
    #This exception raised if the file has parse errors in it
    logging.error("XSD: " + log.message)
    raise Exception, log.message
```

Running `2to3`

```
# As needed: pip install 2to3
> 2to3 code.py
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: buffer
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: idioms
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
RefactoringTool: Refactored code.py
--- code.py (original)
+++ code.py (refactored)
@@ -1,8 +1,8 @@
 import logging

 try:
-   print "hello"
-except Exception, log:
+   print("hello")
+except Exception as log:
    #This exception raised if the file has parse errors in it
    logging.error("XSD: " + log.message)
-   raise Exception, log.message
+   raise Exception(log.message)
RefactoringTool: Files that need to be modified:
RefactoringTool: code.py
```